# How do I create an entry with a compound key with Couchbase?

Tags: node.js, couchbase

I have some code running in NodeJS that sets the doc in the database:

```
    cb.set(req.body.id, req.body.value, function (err, meta) {
      res.send(req.body);
    });
```

I have read about compound keys and it seems that feature can simplify my life. The question is how to properly add an entry with a compound key? The code below fails and messages that a string was expected, no array.

```
    cb.set([req.body.id, generate_uuid()], req.body.value, function (err, meta) {
      res.send(req.body);
    });
```

So should I convert my array to a string like '["patrick_bateman", 'uuid_goes_here']'?

Answer (score 0):

If you're speaking about [this "compound keys"](http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-devguide-2.0/using-compound-keys-group-by.html)...

This compuond keys aren't set by user directly, they are made by couchbase server while you use view. In couchbase view you can create map functions that will use "compund keys". Example:

```
map: function() {
  if (doc.type === "mytype"){
    emit([doc.body.id, doc.uuid], null);
  }
}
```

In this case couchbase will create index by that "compund key" and when you query view you'll be able to set "two" keys.

This is useful i.e. in situations when you need to get some documents that varied by some time range. Example, you have docs with type "message" and you want to get all docs that have created from time `4` to `7`.

In this case map function will look like:

```
map: function(){
  if (meta.type === "json"){
    emit([doc.type, doc.timestamp], null);
  }
}
```

and query will contain params `startKey=["message", 4]` and `endKey=["message", 7]`.

But also you can create complex keys like "message:4" and then query it via simple get. I.e. if you use sequential ids (by using increment function) for that messages you can easily iterate through that messages using simple `for` loop and `couchbase.get` function.

Also check this [blog post](http://tugdualgrall.blogspot.com/2012/11/building-chat-application-using-nodejs.html) by [Tug Grall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1648508/tug-grall) about creating chat application with nodejs and couchbase.